# Matlab debugging - beginner level

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

I am a total beginner in Matlab and trying to write some Machine Learning Algorithms in Matlab. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me in debugging this code.

```
function y = KNNpredict(trX,trY,K,X)
   % trX is NxD, trY is Nx1, K is 1x1 and X is 1xD
   % we return a single value 'y' which is the predicted class

% TODO: write this function
% int[] distance = new int[N];
distances = zeroes(N, 1);
examples = zeroes(K, D+2);
i = 0;
% for(every row in trX) { // taking ONE example
for row=1:N, 
 examples(row,:) = trX(row,:);
 %sum = 0.0;
 %for(every col in this example) { // taking every feature of this example
 for col=1:D, 
    % diff = compute squared difference between these points - (trX[row][col]-X[col])^2
    diff =(trX(row,col)-X(col))^2;
    sum += diff;
 end % for
 distances(row) = sqrt(sum);
 examples(i:D+1) = distances(row);
 examples(i:D+2) = trY(row:1);
end % for

% sort the examples based on their distances thus calculated
sortrows(examples, D+1);
% for(int i = 0; i < K; K++) {
% These are the nearest neighbors
pos = 0;
neg = 0;
res = 0;
for row=1:K,
    if(examples(row,D+2 == -1))
        neg = neg + 1;
    else
        pos = pos + 1;
    %disp(distances(row));
    end
end % for

if(pos > neg)
    y = 1;
    return;
else
    y = -1;
    return;
end
end
end
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you describe what you want the function to do and how it seems to be going wrong?

Comment: Hi Jouni, Thanks for getting back. So this is the K nearest neighbors. I get an error "Function sum has too many arguments" error - for one. Also since am a beginner, I am kind of confused with the matlab syntax for matrix indices and access. So I wanted to know if you see any weird things going on in my code. Thanks.

Comment: start by displaying the error message. Also, you don't define either N, or D in the code. zeroes should be zeros....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with matrices in MATLAB, it is usually better to avoid excessive loops and instead use vectorized operations whenever possible. This will usually produce faster and shorter code.

In your case, the k-nearest neighbors algorithm is simple enough and can be well vectorized. Consider the following implementation:

```
function y = KNNpredict(trX, trY, K, x)
    %# euclidean distance between instance x and every training instance
    dist = sqrt( sum( bsxfun(@minus, trX, x).^2 , 2) );

    %# sorting indices from smaller to larger distances
    [~,ord] = sort(dist, 'ascend');

    %# get the labels of the K nearest neighbors
    kTrY = trY( ord(1:min(K,end)) );

    %# majority class vote
    y = mode(kTrY);
end
```

Here is an example to test it using the Fisher-Iris dataset:

```
%# load dataset (data + labels)
load fisheriris
X = meas;
Y = grp2idx(species);

%# partition the data into training/testing
c = cvpartition(Y, 'holdout',1/3);
trX = X(c.training,:);
trY = Y(c.training);
tsX = X(c.test,:);
tsY = Y(c.test);

%# prediction
K = 10;
pred = zeros(c.TestSize,1);
for i=1:c.TestSize
    pred(i) = KNNpredict(trX, trY, K, tsX(i,:));
end

%# validation
C = confusionmat(tsY, pred)
```

The confusion matrix of the kNN prediction with K=10:

```
C =
    17     0     0
     0    16     0
     0     1    16
```